# "ACPI Error" when I connect a flashdrive

Tags: acpi

I connected a flash drive to my laptop to install Ubuntu 24.04 and while running Ubuntu from the flash drive, I encountered this error that I do not know what It is and there is no information about it.

[image: ACPI errors]

You can see the errors more clearly here:

```
[0.2700371] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object ...
[0.2700371] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog ...
[0.2700371] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object ...
[0.2700371] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog ...
[0.7990421]ACPI Error: No handler for region ...
[0.7990421]ACPI Error: Region ...
[0.7990421]ACPI Error: Aborting method ...
```

I hope someone knows how to solve this problem

Comment: 24.04 wont be released for years.

Comment: Check this out: It is another forum, with a similar issue. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/acpi-error-what-means-4175605357/

Comment: @David I edited it, hopefully they accept the edit.

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format; ie. 20.04 is the 2020-April release of Ubuntu (2000 is added to the year), so your 24.04 signifies a 2024-April release?  As stated already; that'll be the release in 2+ years from now, with development starting end-October-2023.  Most of us don't have *blue phone boxes* & can't travel in time... unless you can I'd check your question for typos/errors.

Comment: I am sorry. It was a typo. I wanted to put 21.10. This is the lastest ubuntu version.